# Some MP3s have to be synced multiple times before tags are read properly

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

I've been having trouble with tags not being read on the first try.

Say I rip a CD to MP3, tag it properly (typically both ID3v2.4 and ID3v1.1 tags) with Picard and/or Puddletag, then move it to my Music directory so it is synced with U1. The files will all sync, but 1 or 2 tracks off each album will show up as "Unknown Artist" in the Android application. It doesn't matter if I wait minutes or days, the tags never get scanned or fixed.

The only thing that works is moving the affected files to another folder temporarily then moving them back so they are uploaded again.

Now this isn't a showstopper, but it's an annoyance that I have to re-sync probably 10-20% of my music because the tags aren't scanned properly on the first try. This has happened consistently since I first signed up for the service last year.

Is this a known issue or do I seem to be the only one affected?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't appear to be a open bug for this on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone

I suggest you open a new bug: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone/+filebug

Comment: Thanks, I went ahead and submitted it here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-android-music/+bug/741066

Answer (score 2):

This issue should now be fixed.